# Why was the origin of the Apollo lunar module coordinate system "underground"?

Tags: apollo-program, lander, coordinates

Even stranger than the origin of the [Saturn V coordinate system](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36120/26446) is that of the lunar module:

> The X-axis station reference measurements (inches) start at a design reference point identified as station +X200.000. This reference point is approximately 128 inches above the bottom surface of the footpads (with the landing gear extended) ; therefore, all X-axis station reference measurements are +X-measurements.
>
> LMA790-3-LM *Apollo Operations Handbook: Lunar Module*

As seen in this diagram, this places the origin of the coordinate system 72.85 inches below the bottom of the footpads that rest on the moon's surface, and 5.35 inches below the tip of the touchdown sensors.  In other words, the origin of the coordinate system is outside the spacecraft and "underground" when on the moon.

Why was this reference point chosen?

[image: LM coordinate system]

Comment: I'm guessing that it was chosen so that (a) all reference positions including the end of the surface contact probes have positive X coordinates and (b) the ascent/descent stage separation plane is at a round multiple of 100 inches.

Comment: Good grief, the [shuttle coordinate system](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts_coord.html) is positive-down with the orbiter's zero ref being 236 inches in front of the nose....

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Oh my, that *is* strange.

Comment: What? The shuttle system makes total sense! That's why these Apollo ones seem bizarre to me.

Comment: I left out the ironic smiley from my last comment...

Comment: @RussellBorogove point (b) - the diagram states - top right - x-axis design reference points start at +200 (which is indicated on the diagram at the separation plane)

Comment: Can’t answer on LM case specifically, but often the reference point is chosen based on the rig the equipment is being assembled on. So maybe there was a hard fixed base there at the Grumman’s factory.